# gtk TextView widget doesn't update during function

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm new to GUI programming with python and gtk, so this is a bit of a beginners question.
I have a function that is called when a button is pressed which does various tasks, and a TextView widget which I write to after each task is completed.  The problem is that the TextView widget doesn't update until the entire function has finished. I need it to update after each task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After each update to the TextView call

```
while gtk.events_pending():
  gtk.main_iteration()
```

You can do your update through a custom function:

```
def my_insert(self, widget, report, text):

  report.insert_at_cursor(text)
  while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()
```

From the PyGTK FAQ:
[How can I force updates to the application windows during a long callback or other internal operation?](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq03.007.htp)